# SQL injection security vulnerability in Plesk control pannel

Tags: security, sql

I have plesk 10.3.1 and I received following email from the Plesk admin

> Parallels, the manufacturer and distributor of the Plesk Control
>   Panel, has identified a SQL injection security vulnerability in some
>   older versions of the control panel. This vulnerability is considered
>   critical in nature and Parallels advises that you take action quickly.
>
> Parallels released a "MicroUpdate" that makes patching this
>   vulnerability easy. Please refer to the following Parallels Knowledge
>   Base article for the MicroUpdate file as well as instructions and a
>   complete list of affected control panel versions:
>   http://kb.parallels.com/en/113321

```
root@***:/# cat /root/.autoinstaller/microupdates.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<patches>
    <product id="plesk" version="10.3.1" installed-at="not-a-date-time">
        <patch version="17" timestamp="" installed-at="20120207T062525" />
    </product>
</patches>
```

I refered the document I got the follwoing solugion

```
 ... fixes are provided by the Micro-Updates listed below:
8.6.0 for Linux only MU#2 - http://kb.parallels.com/en/112181
9.5.4  for Linux only MU#11 - http://kb.parallels.com/en/112179
10.0.1 for Linux and Windows MU#13 - http://kb.parallels.com/en/113322
10.1.1 for Linux and Windows MU#22 - http://kb.parallels.com/en/113323
10.2.0 for Linux and Windows MU#16 - http://kb.parallels.com/en/113324
10.3.1 for Linux and Windows MU#5 - KB is absent
```

Does it mean I have already update to latest version and I dont need to worry about the threat??  Please help me...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by http://kb.parallels.com/en/9294, you just need to run

```
# $PRODUCT_ROOT_D/admin/sbin/autoinstaller --select-product-id plesk --select-release-current --reinstall-patch --install-component base
```

Comment: Thanks ivan..  I saw the MU17 is installed and it is the latest for 10.3.1..  I read tat all the versions above MU#5 have fixed the problem...Please suggest me if I am wrong..

Comment: I would have run it once without caring about what is installed - it would install the latest patch that is available. Yes, 10.3.1 MU#17 should be later than MU#5 :^) and have the problem solved.